# How do I create a thumbnail from an image using C# Win Mobile 6.5/Compact framework?

Tags: c#, .net, image, thumbnails, windows-mobile-6.5

I am trying to make/use a smaller image than the one taken with the camera to display in parts of my program (due to memory issues...)

Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to find ways to make a smaller image/thumbnail on the mobile device - the way it is possible in normal windows...

Is there a way to make a smaller image on **Win Mobile 6.5/Compact Framework?**

For example  - these do not work on Win Mobile

[What is the "best" way to create a thumbnail using ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-thumbnail-using-asp-net/27938#27938)

[This looks promising](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) - but i want to just put the image on a PictureBox - and not sure how to use this to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

This code should be work. I have also implemented this code. For that I have used OpenNETCF.Drawing.dll.

```
 barray = GetImage(filepath);
                        if (barray != null)
                        {
                            ms.Write(barray, 0, barray.Length - 1);
                            imageBitmap = CreateThumbnail(ms, new Size(PreviewImageWidth, PreviewImageHeight));
                            bm = ImageUtils.IBitmapImageToBitmap(imageBitmap);

                           // m_CurrentImageID = Convert.ToInt32(lstPic.ToList()[index].Id);
                            PictureBox ib = ((PictureBox)this.imagePanel.Controls[(nIndex * 2) + 1]);
                            ib.Image = bm;
}

 private byte[] GetImage(string FilePath)
        {
            byte[] barray;

            if (File.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                FileInfo _fileInfo = new FileInfo(FilePath);
                long _NumBytes = _fileInfo.Length;
                FileStream _FStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader _BinaryReader = new BinaryReader(_FStream);
                barray = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(_NumBytes));
                _FStream.Flush();
                _FStream.Dispose();
                return barray;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }

public IBitmapImage CreateThumbnail(Stream stream, Size size)
        {
            IBitmapImage imageBitmap;
            ImageInfo ii;
            IImage image;
            ImagingFactory factory = new ImagingFactoryClass();
            try
            {

                factory.CreateImageFromStream(new StreamOnFile(stream), out image);
                image.GetImageInfo(out ii);
                factory.CreateBitmapFromImage(image, (uint)size.Width, (uint)size.Height, ii.PixelFormat, InterpolationHint.InterpolationHintDefault, out imageBitmap);
                return imageBitmap;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CreateLogFiles Err = new CreateLogFiles();
                Err.ErrorLog(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                imageBitmap = null;
                image = null;
                factory = null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"\path to image").GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, IntPtr.Zero);
```

but the quality of thumbnail may not be as good. For quality thumbnail images you could refer to this post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/acoat/archive/2007/05/09/resize-images-a-thumbnail-maker.aspx)

Comment: I am aware of those calls, but this does not work on Compact framework/Win mobile - but thanks.